# Allow Guests to Upload to Directory?

Tags: ee2, solspace-freeform

We have a Freeform field for uploading files to an EE directory.  However, it appears there’s no way in EE to allow for Guests to upload to a directory?  Under File Upload Preferences we can see each of the Member Groups we’ve created but there is simply no option present for Guests.

Am I missing something?  Is there any way to simply define an upload path manually for the field as opposed to being forced to select one of the directories created under File Upload Preferences?

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at Ben's fantastic LogMeIn add-on?

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/logmein

It'll automatically login a member, after you've defined a custom member group & directory for the anonymous visitor.