# Allow Guests to Upload to Directory? FreeForm PRO / EE2.6.1

Tags: solspace-freeform, file-uploads

This question was asked earlier and the suggestion was the devot-ee addon LogMeIn.

Can anyone clarify that this is the only option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow Guests to Upload to Directory?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13686/allow-guests-to-upload-to-directory)

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I am testing with LogMeIn and it does not seem to work, there is basically no documentation and there has not been any support on their site since 2012.  I cannot find anything that confirms that it works with EE 2.6.1.

So my question is - are there any other options to let a guest upload a file?

I am using FreeForm PRO.   The upload works for me (SuperAdmin), but not when I submit the form as a guest.  There must be an option - you wouldnt require signin for Contact Us forms - but I have not figured it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to give your member group permissions to upload files in the "[File Upload Preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html)".

The setting is at the bottom of the page under the heading "[Restrict file uploading to select member groups](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html#restrict-file-uploading-to-select-member-groups)".

[image]

Comment: "Guests" are not included in this list.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to append `[]` to the end of your file field's name. Simply using `{freeform:field_name}` or `{composer:field_name}` doesn't do it automatically.