# Guest upload expression engine

Tags: safecracker, guest

I know that by default EE doesn't allow guests to upload a file. Though a client really needs this feature in his site. Isn't there a possibility to enable this for guests as well?

I guess I would then need to have a look at specific code pieces to enable this but I can't seem to figure out where this might be located, did anyone ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a duplicate of : [Allow Guests to Upload to Directory? FreeForm PRO / EE2.6.1](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14489/allow-guests-to-upload-to-directory-freeform-pro-ee2-6-1)

Try the answer there, and let us know how you get on.

In short Guests should be able to upload (like any other group) **if** you set the relivent permissions. This will be "Can post to (channel where the files are attached)" (Channel Assignment &  Channel Posting Privileges sections). Permissions can be found at Members > Member Groups > Edit Group (Guests)

Also, you'll need to review your File Upload preferences (Content > Files > File Upload Preferences), at the bottom of this section is the part that the duplicate post refers too). I do note here that Guest group is removed (as well as banned, super admins ect), I suggest a work around of cloning the Guest group with all the same permissions, set this group as the anonymous group (Member > Preferences) and it *should* appear in the File Upload Preferences.