# Channel Form file uploads in Matrix/Grid field not working for guest users

Tags: matrix, file-uploads, channel-form, grid, guest

I have created a Channel Form that is intended for guest users (not logged in) to submit information including up to two image files. The form uses a Matrix or Grid field (I've tried both) for the image files. The form works great except that the image files are not uploaded. If I login as a Super Admin and submit the form, the files ARE uploaded, which leads me to believe it is some sort of permissions issue on the upload directory.

I set /images/uploads and /images/uploads/habitats to 777 to try that, and it is still not working.

FORM CODE:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="Habitats" return="/habitats/thank-you" 
logged_out_member_id="6" 
rules:habitat_story="max_length[500]" 
rules:habitat_comments="max_length[500]" 
rules:habitat_management_practices="max_length[500]" 
rules:habitat_category_other="max_length[50]" 
rules:habitat_program_other="max_length[128]"
}

...

<fieldset>
    <label for="habitat_photos">{label:habitat_photos}</label>
    {instructions:habitat_photos}
    {field:habitat_photos}
</fieldset>

...

{/exp:channel:form}
```

Can anyone offer a solution or advice to fix my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I forgot to give upload permission to my new member group (the one I created for the anonymous submitter) in the File Upload destination preferences. I went in and did that, and now the form is working correctly. :)

Answer (score 3):

By default, the members of the guests group cannot upload to EE; this is a permissions issue, but, it's permissions within EE, not with the filesystem, which is why CHMOD'ing to 777 didn't help.

[Here's a link to a previous post with this problem, and a solution](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13686/allow-guests-to-upload-to-directory).

Comment: Thanks, Nick. This may or may not be a great solution. However, I realized I forgot to give upload permission to my new member group (for the anonymous submitters) in the File Upload destination preferences. Now it's working!!!